# How to display configurable product price instead of "From $..."?

Tags: magento2, price, configurable-price

For example, I have a configurable product like below:

- configurable product, price 999
- its simple product: size S, price 799, special price 599
- its simple product: size M, price 799
- its simple product: size L, price 999
- its simple product: size XL, price 799
- its simple product: size XXL, price 799

I want the initial price to be taken from the configurable product on which I set the price instead of the most cheapest simple product or text like "From $599".

How to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your block class could work? You could then call this method in your template via `$lowestPrice = $block->getLowestVariantPrice($configurableProduct);`

```php
private \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency;
private \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurableOptionsProviderInterface $configurableOptionsProvider;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
 * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurableOptionsProviderInterface $configurableOptionsProvider
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurableOptionsProviderInterface $configurableOptionsProvider
) {
    $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    $this->configurableOptionsProvider = $configurableOptionsProvider;
}

/**
 * @param ProductInterface $product
 * @return ?string
 */
public function getLowestVariantPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product): ?string
{
    $lowestPrice = null;
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $variant */
    foreach ($this->configurableOptionsProvider->getProducts($product) as $variant) {
        $variantAmount = (float)$variant->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
        if ($lowestPrice === null || ($variantAmount < $lowestPrice)) {
            $lowestPrice = $variantAmount;
        }
    }
    return $lowestPrice !== null ? $this->formatPrice($lowestPrice) : null;
}

/**
 * @param string|float $price
 * @return string
 */
private function formatPrice($price): string
{
    return $this->priceCurrency->format($price, false, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear but that's not the point.
By default, magento displays the price on the configurable product: "From: $599", and when you select a variant - the price reloads.
I want it to display the price taken from the configurable product (that's how it doesn't work now) and change according to the selected size (that's how the standard now works).